# Empty input field in javascript should alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code, but it does not tell the user when the input field is empty as it should. Can anybody see what's wrong?

```js
$('#age_validation_btn').click(function() {
  var age = $('#age_validation_input').val(); 
  if (parseInt(age) == '') {
    alert('Please type in something');

  } else {
    if (new Date().getFullYear() - parseInt(age) >= 18) {
      (function() {
        var link = document.getElementById('btn-close-modal');
        link.click();
      })();
    } else {
      alert('younger then 18');
    }

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="age_validation_input" />
<input type="button" id="age_validation_btn" value="valid "/>
```

```html
<input maxlength="4" id="age_validation_input" size="33" align="middle" style="background-color: rgba(191, 186, 168, 0.8); border:none; height:90px; width:380px; color:#3d3b33; padding:15px; font-size:70px; font-weight:bold;"></font> 
 <br /><br />
<input type="button" id="age_validation_btn" style="background-color: rgba(99, 95, 82, 0.8); border:none; height:65px; width:410px; color:#c4bda4; font-size:40px; font-weight:bold;" value="OK" />
```

Hope you can help :-)

Comment: can you put the exact `code`? where is the button?

Comment: At the first place, It's wrong `if (parseInt(age) == '')` you convert it to integer then compare it to string. Obviously it will result to false which is will proceed to else.

Comment: I have added the button code. How can I check if the parseInt(age) is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st if you use Jquery don't use native JavaScript like `document.getElementById` use `$('#the-id')` instead.

2nd when you cast/parse numeric value to integer with `parseInt` set the second (radix) parameter - `parseInt(age, 10)` because different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified.

3rd this is how i do it

```
$('my-button-selector').on('click', function() {

    var age = parseInt($('age-input-selector').val(), 10);

    if(isNaN(age)) {
        alert('Numeric value is required for Age!');
        return false;//stop the validation here
    }

    if(new Date().getFullYear() - age >= 18) {
        $('#btn-close-modal').trigger('click');
    } else {
        alert('Younger than 18!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `parseInt("")` returns `NaN` not the empty string `''` you are expecting. view the parseInt docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: How should it be written then?

Comment: As followed : `if (age == '') {`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try it remove parseInt

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$('#age_validation_btn').click(function() {
  var age = $('#age_validation_input').val();
  
 if (age == '') {
  
  alert('Please type in something');
  
 } else {
  
  if (new Date().getFullYear() - age >= 18) {
    (function() {
                var link = document.getElementById('btn-close-modal');
                link.click();
            })(); 
  }
  else {
    alert('younger then 18');  
  }
  
 }
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following code helps :)

```
if($.trim(age).length == 0) {

    alert('Please type in something');

}
```